# What is the safest distance to create a star?

Tags: astronomy

What is the safest distance we could create a star without affecting the gravitational force of our solar system?

Thanks.

Comment: Can I suggest you say how big a star in your post, one with the same mass as the sun maybe?

Comment: It's going to depend on a lot of issues, including time span, since over enough time even distant stars can rumble by way too close. We live in a region sparse enough to make a few billion years of safety plausible.

Comment: We can't create stars, but calculating the gravitational influence of a star of given mass at a given distance is a straightforward exercise. What's the conceptual question here?

Answer (score 1):

Assume a star the same mass as the sun.

Now you have to figure out how far the sun has a gravitational influence, in theory, this is infinite, in practice, let's take it as far out as the proposed Oort cloud, which is composed of icy planetesimals, perhaps like Pluto or large comets.

I choose that distance because as far as I know if this cloud exists, it is far enough away to be influenced by other stars.

That puts the distance as 100,000 astronomical units, which is 1.58 light years away.

So the new sun would need to fulfil the same idea as above, it would have to be at least 1.58 light years further on out into the void,  to make sure it did not disturb anything in the solar system. That gives a total distance of 3.16 light years, to be safe in our beds.

This is closer to our sun than our next nearest star, Proxima Centauri, which is 4 light years away, but which has only about 1/8 of the mass of the Sun.

So, a star with the same mass as our sun would need to be 3.16 (say 3) light years away from our sun, so as not to produce significant gravitational effects on our solar system.

Comment: I'd explain the philosophy behind "doubling" to get to 3 light years, for future generations to understand. Other than that,  excellent answer.

Comment: Other stars come closer than this quite frequently I think.

Comment: I would believe it Rob. Was thinking how small distance is when doing it then I thought, it's comparable to P. Centuri  So looks ok as distance goes.